# Compare two files, if match, only last two field will be shift down (awk)

Tags: awk, compare

I have two input files (tab delimited) and I need find match between them for the $1 && $2 if the match only 3rd and 4th field will be shifted down:

INPUT:

#### File1:

```
p1   555 
p1   557 
p3   558
```

#### File2:

```
p1  323 lololo  aaaa    
p1  555 papapp  kkka    
p1  556 hooho   sssa    
p1  557 jjjlo   kkka    
p3  424 zzzzz   llla    
p3  558 jjjjj   ssss
```

OUTPUT:

```
p1 323  lololo aaaa
p1 555
          papaapp kkka
p1 556   hooho   sssa
p1 557   
          jjjlo kkka
 etc.
```

I have for comparison:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' file1 file2
```

But how to do condition for it I do not know:

```
awk '{if ($1$2file1 == $1$2file2) print $1$2"\n"$3$4; else print $0}' ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}
           {k=$1 FS $2;if(k in a){print k;$1=$2=FS}print}' file1 file2
```

with your data:

```
kent$  head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
p1      555
p1      557
p3      558

==> f2 <==
p1      323     lololo  aaaa
p1      555     papapp  kkka
p1      556     hooho   sssa
p1      557     jjjlo   kkka
p3      424     zzzzz   llla
p3      558     jjjjj   ssss

kent$  awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{k=$1 FS $2;if(k in a){print k;$1=$2=FS}print}' f1 f2   
p1      323     lololo  aaaa
p1      555
                 papapp kkka
p1      556     hooho   sssa
p1      557
                 jjjlo kkka
p3      424     zzzzz   llla
p3      558
                 jjjjj ssss
```

Comment: If I can have another question (I hope easy question..). If I would like to shift down only 3rd and 4th column down and 1st and 2nd will be on same position (from second file in result). so will be p1\t323\tlololo\taaaa\np1\t555\np1\t556\tpapapp\tkkka? Thank you

Comment: @fedulka maybe you can ask a new question? the desired text format in comment cannot be read....

Comment: I added it..I would not to duplicate similar question, but yes, you have right..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178455/compare-two-files-if-match-shifted-down-last-fields-awk

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator will tell you whether the `$1$2` value from file2 was seen in file1. This has an advantage over something like checking `c[$1$2] > 0`as the latter will actually create an entry for `$1$2` even if it hadn't existed before (with value equivalent to `0`, so still works, but we don't need to create it so nice to avoid that side effect by using `in` instead).

**EDIT**: Use the comma separator in the array index so that the SUBSEP value is inserted between `$1` and `$2`, avoiding the issue so rightly pointed out in the comments.

```
$ cat tf.awk
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
NR==FNR {c[$1,$2]; next}
{if (($1,$2) in c) print $1,$2 RS OFS OFS $3, $4; else print}

$ awk -f tf.awk file1 file2
p1  323 lololo  aaaa
p1  555
        papapp  kkka
p1  556 hooho   sssa
p1  557
        jjjlo   kkka
p3  424 zzzzz   llla
p3  558
        jjjjj   ssss
```

Comment: `a[$1$2]` not safe. think about  `p1 12` and `p11 2`.

Comment: Thanks, @Kent, yikes, completely right. Edited to use `SUBSEP`.