# Compare two files, if match shifted down last fields (awk)

Tags: awk, merge

I have two input files (tab delimited) and i need find match between them for the $1 && $2 if the match only 3rd and 4th field will be shifted down :

INPUT:
File1:

```
 p1   555  
 p1   557  
 p3   558
```

File2:

```
p1  323 lololo  aaaa    
p1  555 papapp  kkka    
p1  556 hooho   sssa    
p1  557 jjjlo   kkka    
p3  424 zzzzz   llla    
p3  558 jjjjj   ssss
```

OUTPUT:

```
p1 323  lololo aaaa
p1 555
p1 556  papaapp kkka
p1 557   
p3 424  hooho   sssa
p3 558      
        jjjlo   kkka
```

etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { to_shift[$1,$2] = 1; next } { queue[++w] = $3 OFS $4 } to_shift[$1, $2] { print $1, $2; next } { print $1, $2, queue[++r] } END { while(r != w) { print OFS OFS queue[++r] } }' file1 file2
```

That is:

```
NR == FNR {                      # while processing the first file (file1)
  to_shift[$1,$2] = 1            # remember which lines to shift
  next                           # and do nothing else
}
{                                # afterwards (processing file2):
  queue[++w] = $3 OFS $4         # queue the next payload fields
}
to_shift[$1, $2] {               # If this is a shift line
  print $1, $2                   # print only the first two fields
  next                           # and do nothing else
}
{                                # otherwise, print the first two fields and
  print $1, $2, queue[++r]       # the next queued payload
}
END {                            # In the end:
  while(r != w) {                # print out what remains in the queue, i.e.
    print OFS OFS queue[++r]     # all that was shifted out at the bottom
  }
}
```

I suspect that for formatting you may want to use `\t` as output field separator, in which case you could simply pass `-v OFS='\t'` to `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == FNR { to_shift[$1,$2] = 1; next } { queue[++w] = $3 OFS $4 } to_shift[$1, $2] { print $1, $2; next } { print $1, $2, queue[++r] } END { while(r != w) { print OFS OFS queue[++r] } }' file1 file2
```

If the input is tab-separated and fields can contain spaces, also pass `-F '\t'` to make the input field separator a tab as well.

Comment: Wintermute, thank you for this excellent script and with the comment, I appreciate it.